# Trouble writing .tif from memory directly into S3 Bucket

Tags: python, raster, gdal, amazon-web-services

I've used question on the topic as initial help and structured my code after it. I'm warping a raster file using these `kwargs`

```
rast = gdal.Open(/vsicurl/raster_url)
wkt = rast.GetProjection()
outbounds = [-180.00, -90.00, 180.00, 90.00]
warp_kwargs = {
                'format': 'vrt',
                'srcSRS': wkt,
                'dstSRS': 'EPSG:4326',
                'outputBounds': outbounds,
                'options':['SOURCE_EXTRA=1000','CENTER_LONG=0']
            }

gdal.Warp('/vsimem/rast_1.tif', rast, **warp_kwargs)
```

I then used [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375823/how-to-write-gdal-translate-output-from-memory-directly-to-s3) previous question to try to upload the file from `/vsimem/` directly into an s3 bucket. I changed a couple things, so my code is as follows.
(I use `fp` to mean filepath)

```
def upload_to_s3(mem_fp, s3_fp, bucket_name):
    f = gdal.VSIFOpenL(mem_fp, 'rb')
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(f, 0, 2)  # seek to end
    size = gdal.VSIFTellL(f)
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(f, 0, 0)  # seek to beginning
    data = gdal.VSIFReadL(1, size, f)
    gdal.VSIFCloseL(f)
    # Upload the raw data to s3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    s3.put_object(Key=s3_fp, Bucket=bucket_name, Body=data, ContentLength=size)
```

In this case size is the size of the raster and data is `b'<VRTDataset rasterXSize="1440" rasterYSize="720" subClass="VRTWarpedDataset">`. So this process does upload a file to `s3`, but it's only 3 kb when it should be around 8 mb. And when I try to download the file from `s3` and plot it in QGIS, it errors out saying

```
ERROR 4: : No such file or directory
ERROR 5: GDALWarpOptions.Validate(): hSrcDS is not set.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'test.tif'.
```

I've tried using both `s3.put_object()` and `s3.upload_file()` and neither of them work. I've also tried using an `s3.Object.put()` which didn't work. I've tried putting the raster in `/vsimem/temp` which also didn't work. Not sure what else to try here.

Comment: Have you looked at that small file? Sounds like you uploaded just the VRT which is a text file describing geodata (and possible transformations).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to look at it? What tools would I use? Also if that is the case, do you know how to upload the actual raster? would I just change the format in the warp kwargs to `GTiff`?

Comment: Yep, that seemed to be it. Thank you! I did not realize that you could store GTiff in `/vsimem/` I thought that was for VRTs only. You can submit as an answer if you want!

Comment: In warp kwargs change `'format': 'vrt'` to `'format': 'gtiff'`.  I would consider keeping the warp to VRT, then `gdal.Translate` to a vsimem tif with compression to reduce file size before uploading the tif.

Comment: @user2856 thank you! If you want put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but won't answer as I can't test (no AWS account) and I don't like to post what I haven't tested. BTW have you tried the [`/vsis3/` virtual filesystem](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsis3-aws-s3-files) for writing directly to AWS?

Comment: I have not tried. I did see that in the documentation, but am still kind of confused as to what `vsi` is. I'm confused how it's different from `vsicurl` for reading and `vsimem` for writing. I guess I'll have to play around with it a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue here is within `warp_kwargs`. [User2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856) and [bugmenot123](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/51035/bugmenot123) both pointed this out. Replace `'format':'vrt'` with `'format':'GTiff'`. The file that was getting uploaded to `s3` was a vrt and not a tif. I was under the impression that only vrt files could be handled within the `/vsimem/` directory; however, it works with the other gdal supported file formats!

After making that change, the correct raster file is being uploaded to `s3`.